# Composite C1 CMS Assign C# function result to a variable in Razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, composite

I want to assign the result of an Inline C# function in Composite C1 CMS. It's a simple string method. When I try to assign this in the following way:

```
string link = @Function("MyNameSpace.GetLocWebsite", new { code = countryCode });
```

I see an CS1003 error:

> Failed to load function 'MyNameSpace.Redirect'
>   D:!PROJEKTY!!!BRANCHES\FMM_trunk\Website\App_Data\Razor\MyNameSpace\Redirect.cshtml(35): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected

Does anybody know how to correctly assign a function result to variable ?

Comment: wisniowy: Any solution?